# Ruby-on-rails trying to get text and link_to on the same screen line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css-float, view

Ruby on rails - trying to change how a page (view) displays.

I am currently using float to display an index page with some text as well as an image.
I wish to have the text (markdown post.body) see below end with ... followed by "more" (where more is an underlined link).  Currently "more" appears on a new line.

that is I get
... 
"the compiled JavaScript code. The second command is "Run", which compiles the code in your editor and evaluates the JavaScript and shows you the result of ...

more"

what I want is
...
"the compiled JavaScript code. The second command is "Run", which compiles the code in your editor and evaluates the JavaScript and shows you the result of ...more"

I have pasted in relevent part of view below 
app/views/posts/index

```
<div class= "article-face-img"> 
  <%  face_image = article_face_image post %>
  <%= image = image_tag face_image, size: "260x205", class: "article-face-img" %>
  <h1><%= post.title  %>  </h1>
  <%= dateconvert post.updated_at %>
  <%= markdown post.body[0..1250] + "..." %>
  <%= link_to 'more', post %>  
</div>
```

where "article_face_image" and "markdown" are helper methods.

from the css

```
// for posts to align image and text  
.article-face-img{
  float: left;
  padding: .8em;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

I have tried a number of things including trying to add the post_body to the link before display e.g.

```
<% a = markdown post.body[0..1250] + "..."%>
<% b = link_to 'more', post %>
<%= a = a + b %>
```

any help appreciated
thanks
Pierre

Comment: Hi! Can you add the HTML output of `<%= markdown post.body[0..1250] + "..." %>`? Thanks.

Comment: You can see the Posts index page here (http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/).  Please note image not showing (e.g.image-3 is a seperate isse and will probably have to use Amzon's S3 stuff). Thanks - Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the `markdown` embeds your text within a `<p>...<p/>` tag, and this is why your `more` appears on a separate line from the markdown code.

I would work this around with:

```
<%= markdown post.body[0..1250] + "... #{link_to 'more', post}" %>
```

basically embedding the link within your marked down string.

Comment: Thanks all - answer above which I just voted up worked - Pierre